Is it possible in new fortran version (2018, 2023) to overload assignment operator with an array at the LHS?
I read the following post : access operators "[ ], ( ), { }" overloading in Fortran 90 or 2003 and I would like to know if the situation has changed in new fortran versions (2008, 2018, 2023).
In a few words, I work on a large fortran code (over 10000 lines) that uses standard 2D arrays. There are many lines like this : a(i,j)=k. I plan to work on very large arrays which exceed memory size. However, the 2D arrays are very sparse and values are redundant. So, a derived datatype has been defined to take this in account and reduce memory use. But, it will be a very huge task to modify each assignment line in the orginal code.
So, I wonder if it it possible, now, to overload the assignment operator to assign array element by keeping the original syntax : a(i,j)=k
If it is not possible, any suggestion to avoid many changes in the original code will be appreciated.

What have tried?  Need to see a bit of code to offer any actual help.

Indexing is not an operator, it is indexing. Cannot be overloaded. Assignment is not an operator either, it is assignment. Can be overloaded using defined assignments. Neither of that has changed in recent versions of Fortran. As  steve wrote, hard to ask for suggestions how to reduce the changes without the code.
